# Set up default "alter session" for an Oracle user

Tags: oracle, session, configuration

For a JDBC application I need to issue a few ALTER SESSION commands. I do not want to put those into the application code itself. Is there a way to specify defaults for the session parameters for the database schema that the application uses (on the database side) ?

Comment: @Thilo, Thanks you just saved me lots of time!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

most session parameters are defined by the client application. If you want to override the client settings you could create a `DATABASE TRIGGER`. For example, this will create a `LOGON` trigger on the `BAR` schema:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bar.foo
   AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE WHEN (USER = 'BAR')
BEGIN
   dbms_session.set_nls('NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS', '''.,''');
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=hr';
END foo;
```

Comment: An on-logon database trigger is the only way to do this without an application code change.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but could you make the application call a stored procedure that set the session variables whenever a session is created?  Then, you could modify the stored procedure on the server side when needed.

Comment: The point is to not change the application code at all. If I change it to include some actions on session creation (such as call a stored procedure), I would probably make these actions configurable (such as reading them from a file), so that I might as well include the ALTER SESSION calls directly.